# Why is the formatting of my text overlapping, weirdly spaced, and running off the page?

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, sectioning, links

My paper is mostly divided into two columns and I am using the section command. In my final section, where I am including references, some lines have spaces, some don't, several of the lines overlap even though others stay in the two column format, and the whole section is running off the page. I am including links and spaces between each chunk of text, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, I'm getting an error message that says "underfull \hbox..." and "overfill hbox..." Here's a small example of what I wrote:

```
\section{References}\label{sec: references}

{Read, Randy, September 2009. "Basic Diffraction: waves, interference and reciprocal space." Structural Medicine. \url{https://www-structmed.cimr.cam.ac.uk/Course/Basic_diffraction/Diffraction.html} , July 2019.
}
\newline
\newline
{"Diffraction." Science jrank. \url{https://science.jrank.org/pages/2063/Diffraction.html} , July 2019.
}
```

Comment: `...full \hbox` is a warning (not an error) that TeX is having trouble figuring out how to do the line breaks for that paragraph (a double newline will cause underfull, urls can cause either).  For a bibliography, you'll be much better off using BibLaTeX or Biber so that TeX can format everything.  As for your actual error, it's hard to tell since you have given us enough to go on.  Would you be able to go through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 to create a Minimal Working Example for us?  (Also, to mark code on TeX.SE, use the tick mark over near escape, not the single quote.)

Comment: @Teepeemm - Claims such as "you'll be much better off using BibLaTeX or Biber so that TeX can format everything" are of dubious value. First, it makes it sound like someone can choose to run either biblatex *or* biber, which isn't true. Second, since the OP has given no indication regarding what's going wrong in the formatted bibliography, there is no basis for claiming that biblatex/biber will do a better job than, say, natbib/bibtex at avoiding underfull or overfull lines. I believe it would be more helpful, at this stage, to ask the OP if he/she loads the `xurl` and/or `hyperref` packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how you build the bibliography: By hand, or with the help of a software such as natbib/bibtex or biblatex/biber?